# Why is this code working in codepen but not actual site/fiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

I am forking this code from Codepen to use on my site but I am not sure why it is breaking everywhere other than Codepen. I tried testing it on JS Fiddle too and results are the same. Please have a look:

```js
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

 $(window).load(function(){

  $('.masonry').masonry({
   columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
   gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
   itemSelector: '.item'
  });

 });
    
}(jQuery));
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: black;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 3% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 48.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 48.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: xxspx) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 3% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 48.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 48.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 2.25% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 31.83333%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 2.25%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 31.83333%;
    margin-bottom: 2.25%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 2% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 2%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 23.5%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 1.875% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 18.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 1.875%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 18.5%;
    margin-bottom: 1.875%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 1.8% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 15.16667%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 1.8%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 15.16667%;
    margin-bottom: 1.8%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please have look at the original source on Codepen: https://codepen.io/jdlaplan/pen/Aowpj

JS Fiddle Test Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/12szr1f9/2/

Note: I have presented the compiled CSS here while the Codepen source uses SCSS preprocessor.

Comment: You forgot to include the necessary files on jsFiddle

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, which necessary files?

Comment: [Open the browser's console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). Look at the error message. "jQuery is not defined" should tell you a lot.

Comment: jQuery and Masonry. You're including them on codepen but not jsFiddle, and I'm guessing any other sites where you're having issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the libraries which your code is using (Masonry and jQuery) by adding the following code in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
```

You CodePen had those libraries included, while jsfiddle and original website didn't have it. This was causing the promlem!

```js
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

 $(window).load(function(){

  $('.masonry').masonry({
   columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
   gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
   itemSelector: '.item'
  });

 });
    
}(jQuery));
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: black;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 3% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 48.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 48.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: xxspx) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 3% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 48.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 48.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 2.25% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 31.83333%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 2.25%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 31.83333%;
    margin-bottom: 2.25%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 2% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 23.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 2%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 23.5%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 1.875% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 18.5%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 1.875%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 18.5%;
    margin-bottom: 1.875%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .masonry {
    margin: 1.8% 0;
  }
  .masonry .grid-sizer {
    width: 15.16667%;
  }
  .masonry .gutter-sizer {
    width: 1.8%;
  }
  .masonry .item {
    width: 15.16667%;
    margin-bottom: 1.8%;
  }
  .masonry .item img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x170" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x180" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x190" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x210" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```